# A <Div> section will not stay contained when device size is smaller

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

When the screen size of my web page is on tablets/mobile devices, the top div spills out of it's space and overlaps another part of the screen. I'm using bootstrap grids so perhaps I'm incorrectly using them? Any help at all would be a life saver.

[1st Screenshot showing correct placing on a desktop PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqvXS.png)

[2nd Screenshot showing incorrect placement on an iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AXkm.png)

```
    <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row no gutters header text-left mt-5">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 id="testing-1" class="display-4 text-left">Digital Study Skills Tutor</h1>
            <p class="lead">Free self-help study skills resources for university students</p>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>



    .site-header {
  background: url(img/home-header.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
        }

.site-header .layout-hero {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

    .display-4 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to this webpage? I am unable to recreate this scenario provided in your screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to create this scenario but I will take a shot. You need to use media query in order to restyle the components on your page so that the text and the button do not overflow in the next div. You probably need to make the fonts smaller and make the dimensions of the button smaller to fit the small screen size. Keep adjusting the font size and buttons dimension in the below media query to get the desired result. A media query is used to redefine style for different screen sizes. It is a great way to style your page for responsive web design.
[Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Example of the media query for the smaller screen:

```
@media (max-width:576px) {
  .testing-1 {
        font-size:x;
    }
   .lead {
        font-size: y;
    }
    .btn-lg .btn-primary {
        width: z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Yash, Thank you so much for your help with this one, with a little swapping of sizes etc, I managed to get into the top compartment of the page. Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: no problem! I would recommend looking more into media query for responsive designs in future.

Comment: please also upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Sweet! Media queries for the win!